# Cumulative Distribution Function to pmf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am still quite new to cdf and pmf. When we only have pmf for x = 1, 2 and 4 ,
how should I understand the corresponding cdf as in the pmf for x = 3 doesn't exist. 
Also I tried to draw the piecewise function and I don't know if F(2) should cover 
$2\le x \lt 4 $ or just $2\le x \lt 3$ and leave [3,4) blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=4)=1$ then $P(x=i)=0$, unless $i=1$ or $2$ or $4$, that is, the pmf for the event $\{X=3\}$ does exist: $P(X=3)=0$.

The cdf, by one of the possible two definitions, is 
$$F_1(x)=P(X<x)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if } x\le 1\\
P(X=1),&\text{ if } 1<x\le 2\\
P(X=1)+P(X=2),&\text{ if } 2<x\le 4\\
1,&\text{ if } 4<x
.\end{cases}$$

The cdf, by the other possible definition, is 
$$F_2(x)=P(X\le x)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if } x< 1\\
P(X=1),&\text{ if } 1\le x<2\\
P(X=1)+P(X=2),&\text{ if } 2\le x< 4\\
1,&\text{ if } 4\le x
.\end{cases}$$

In both cases

$$F_1(3)=F_2(3)=P(X=1)+P(X=2).$$

As far as the value of the cdf at $2$:
$$F_1(2)=P(X=1)$$
and
$$F_2(2)=P(X=1)+P(X=2).$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also I am wondering if it is true that if one of the intervals is like $a \le x \lt b$, then$ P( c )$ where $a \lt c \lt b$ is equal to 0 ?

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid, I don't completely understand the question. Do you mean $P(X=c)=0$? Do you mean that $P(X=a)>0$, and $P(X=b)>0$ and no values between $a$ and $ b$ are probable. Then per se, $P(X=c)=0$ for any $c$ for $a<c<b$. In general, if over an interval the cdf is constant then the probability of these values inside the interval are of zero probability.

Comment: sorry for my terrible notation. I meant $P(X = c)$. Thanks again!